# My raw query is not working in Laravel DB::select

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am using the Laravel framework. I want to create one complicated report, so I use the below query in `DB::select.` My issue is that it works sometimes and fails many times. Every time I write the query and upload a file, it works, but after 20 minutes, when I run the report, it shows me the error below.

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "join
> aadf_category_mst" LINE 6: left join aadf_category_mst c on p.cat_id =
> c.cat_id ^

My Report query is mentioned below.

```
select cat_name,name,po_no,po_dt,rla_po_no,rla_dt,wd_state,brand_name,sum(qty) as total_qty, sum(amt) as total
from (
    select c.cat_name, p.po_no,p.dt as po_dt,rl.name,p.rla_po_no,p.rla_dt, p.indent_code,i.wd_state,b.brand_name,i.p_model_id,i.rate_id,r.total,count(*) as qty,
    (r.total*count(*)) as amt
    from aadf_po_mst p 
    left join aadf_category_mst c on p.cat_id = c.cat_id
    left join aadf_indent_mst i on p.indent_code = i.indent_code
    left join aadf_rla_mst rl on p.rla_id = rl.rla_id
    left join aadf_brand_mst b on i.a_brand_id = b.brand_id 
    left join aadf_rate_mst r on i.rate_id = r.id 
    group by c.cat_name,p.po_no,rl.name,p.rla_po_no,p.dt,p.rla_dt, p.indent_code,i.wd_state,b.brand_name,i.p_model_id,i.rate_id,r.total
 ) X
group by cat_name, po_no,wd_state,name,brand_name,rla_po_no,rla_dt,po_dt
order by po_dt DESC
```